# What is the difference between these two list creation codes (one normal for loop with if condition and the other one liner code)

Tags: python

The first code which creates an array with no duplicate members from a string, using a normal for loop and an if condition.

```
u = []
for l in string:
    if l not in u:
        u.append(l)
```

And the second code which does the same thing but in one line.

```
u = []
u = [l for l in string if l not in u]
```

The condition in the one line code is not working and at the end, u always contains all the characters in string.

Comment: In the first case, you create empty `u`, and inside `for loop` you modify it. While in the second case, you first create empty `u`, then build `a list` (using list comprehension), and once building your list is done, you assign it to `u`, so no change in `u` while building the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the list comprehension approach, the object `u` in the condition is fixed as the empty list `[]` so the condition will always be satisfied:

```
u = [l for l in string if l not in u] # here u in the condition is always []
```

With the first approach, the condition `if l not in u` always see the updated `u` so it doesn't add the element if it is already present.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. Is there something in python that helps me fix that? Or should I always use the normal way to create lists if I need to test the list itself?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to use the first approach in cases where you need to see the updated value of the list while you create/update it and list comprehension (the second approach that what we call in Python) is not useful here.

Comment: Thanks Krishna for your help. I hope my question wasn't that dumb.

Comment: Definitely not :) It is one of the good examples to highlight that list comprehension though the preferred approach can not be used for all problems.